# Two RewriteRules in one URL? (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First what I have until now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mypage/site/(.*)$ mypage/index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

That is to have a more beautiful URL string like: (`http://www.example.org/mypage/site/home`)

Now my problem is, that I want to have sub sites and call their with numbers like this examples.

```
http://www.example.org/mypage/site/home/1 //Subsite1
http://www.example.org/mypage/site/home/2 //Subsite2
http://www.example.org/mypage/site/home/3 //Subsite3
```

Problem is that my `.htaccess` code for the sub sites does not work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^mypage/site/home/(.*)$ home/index.php?site=home&amp;amp;amp;homesubsite=$1 [L,QSA]
```

He is just loading the home site without the get parameter which includes the number 1,2,3 etc.. for the respective sub site.

Answer (score 2):

Try This one :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mypage/site/home/([^/]*)\.php$ /mypage/index.php?site=$1 [L]
```